# Does the following Python Class demonstrate the following?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop

I was solving some problems through a textbook to really wrap my head around classes and wondering if anyone could help me figure something out. Below is the class that I'm reviewing:

```py
    class Cart():
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.cart = []
            self.total = 0
        
        def add_to_cart(self, item):
            self.cart.append(item)
            self.total += item.price
```

If the method add_to_cart will work when an object of type MobileDevice or of type ServiceContract is passed to it, does anyone know whether the add_to_cart method demonstrates any of the following and why or why not for each?

1. Inheritance
2. Polymorphism
3. Duck typing
4. Top-down design
5. Functional programming

Answer (score 0):

1. Inheritance => False

   class Person(object):

   ```
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

   def getName(self):
       return self.name

   def isEmployee(self):
       return False
   ```

   class Employee(Person):

   ```
   def isEmployee(self):
       return True
   ```

   emp = Person("User1")

   print(emp.getName(), emp.isEmployee()) -> User1 False

   emp = Employee("User2")

   print(emp.getName(), emp.isEmployee()) -> User2 True
2. Polymorphism => False

   def add(x, y, z=0):
   return x + y + z

   print(add(1, 2))
   print(add(1, 2, 3))
3. Duck typing => False

   class Specialstring:
   def **len**(self):
   return 21

   if **name** == "**main**":
   string = Specialstring()
   print(len(string))
4. Top-down design => False as Python comes under BOTTOM UP APPROACH  not TOP DOWN APPROACH

   **TOP DOWN APPROACH** -> ***Mainly used by structured programming language such as COBOL, Fortran, C, etc.***

   **BOTTOM UP APPROACH** -> ***Mainly used by object oriented programming language such as C++, C#, Python.***
5. Functional programming => False

here in the code, you have used **self**, something which is used while creating method of a class which comes under OOP and in Functional programming we can have only method and no class

Comment: Huh? Can you provide some reasons as to why 'False' for all 5? I was thinking Polymorphism  and Top-Down is true

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there also anyone else who could provide thoughts on whether all 5 are False? I feel like there should be a True somewhere as the textbook wouldn't just give all 5 examples to be False..hm